N=4 Supersymmetric Ward identity
(This question pertains to exercise 4.13 of Elvang and Huang's textbook (which used to be lecture notes). This is not for a class, just to learn some new tools for work).
Consider the expansion of the MHV superamplitude in Grassmann monomials given as  (equation (4.45))
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}_n^{MHV} = A_n[g^-g^-g^+g^+\cdots g^+](\eta_1)^4(\eta_2)^4 + A_n[g^-\lambda^{123}\lambda^4\cdots g^+](\eta_1)^4(\eta_{21}\eta_{22}\eta_{23})(\eta_{34})+\cdots
\end{equation}
The supercharges (or just one) is given by (equation (4.46))
\begin{equation}
\tilde{Q}_A = \sum_{i=1}^n|i\rangle \eta_{iA}
\end{equation}
where $A = 1,2,3,4$ (the number of supercharges $\mathcal{N}=4$). I then want the take the amplitude above, show that from $\tilde{Q}_A \mathcal{A}_n^{MHV} = 0$ will give us the previous Ward identity given in equation (4.32) of the text namely
\begin{equation}
0 = -|1\rangle A_n[\lambda^{123}g^-\lambda^4g^+\cdots g^+] - |2\rangle A_n[g^-\lambda^{123}\lambda^4 g^+\cdots g^+] + |3\rangle A_n[g^-g^-g^+\cdots g^+].
\end{equation}
Now, here is my attempt. The expansion of the first equation is the component amplitude from the superamplitude given in equation (4.43), but for our purposes is missing a term to find the Ward identity above namely
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}_n^{MHV}\supset A_n[\lambda^{123}g^-\lambda^4g^+\cdots g^+](\eta_{11}\eta_{12}\eta_{13})(\eta_2)^4(\eta_{34})
\end{equation}
from which I didn't actually derive from the expansion, but made a guess off of the structure of the previous two terms. If I then select $A=4$ in the $\tilde{Q}_A\mathcal{A}_n^{MHV}=0$ equation, let me first expand the sum of the supercharge
\begin{equation}
\tilde{Q}_{A=4} = \sum_{i=1}^n|i\rangle \eta_{i4} = |1\rangle\eta_{14} + |2\rangle\eta_{24} + |3\rangle\eta_{34} + \cdots
\end{equation}
Now, I am quite poor when it comes to handling differentiation and algebra of Grassmann numbers and variables, so at this point I am lost as to how to compute, but my guess is that I must find something that resembles the following
\begin{align}
0 & = \tilde{Q}_4\mathcal{A}_n^{MHV}\\
& = (\eta_1)^4(\eta_2)^4(\eta_{34})\left(|1\rangle A_n[\lambda^{123}g^-\lambda^4g^+\cdots g^+] + |2\rangle A_n[g^-\lambda^{123}\lambda^4 g^+\cdots g^+] -|3\rangle A_n[g^-g^-g^+\cdots g^+]\right)
\end{align}
which actually stops at the third term (the extra one I included above) since the $g^+$ is the end of the hypermultiplet that $\tilde{Q}$ can lower in terms of helicity. The shortcut way I like to think about it is
\begin{equation}
\tilde{Q}:g^-\rightarrow \tilde{\lambda}\rightarrow S\rightarrow \lambda\rightarrow g^+
\end{equation}
which completely forgets all of the indices but physically it is helpful (note that $\lambda\equiv\lambda^A$ and $\tilde{\lambda}\equiv\tilde{\lambda}_D\sim \lambda^{ABC}$ in the clunky shortcut notation I used).
So my question is, how do I fill in the algebra? I have guess on the structure and what should come out, but not how to get there.
